# gmaps4rails - controller object empty in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am using gmaps4rails and geocoder gem to display all the matching current location from database. This is the code from the controller.

```
def map_view
    @users = User.where(city: params[:city])
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@users) do |user, marker|
      marker.lat user.latitude
      marker.lng user.longitude
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
    puts 'coordinates', @hash
end
```

When I try to use the `@hash` object in the view, the object is null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map_location'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```

The above is the code in the view. The map displays with empty object. The browser console shows this error **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**.

When I print from the controller the object is not null.
[Here is the output from the server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j9Gv.png)

I am new. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're not passing in `nil` values for `marker.lat` and `marker.lng`. Based also from this [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301097/gmaps4rails-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded), *"In your json, you should replace: `longitude` with `lng` and `latitude` with `lat`."* Check this related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/121).

Comment: The passed values are not `nil`. I guess the issue is after the value is being passed in `lat` and `long`.